# How do I upgrade my Alcatel Idol 4s (6070O) from Android 6.0.1 to a newer firmware?

Tags: rooting, root-access, 6.0-marshmallow, rom-flashing, custom-roms

I have an old Alcatel Idol 4s laying around which is on Android 6.0.1 and I was wondering if there's any way to upgrade it to Android 7 or 8? I tried every single method I could find but no luck. Almost every single method needs a rooted device (which I also couldn't find a solution for), I even tried using the Alcatel Mobile Upgrade Tool but it gave me a prompt saying there's no update available, and obviously, I couldn't find any software updates in the settings as well, so I need help.

Comment: If there is no official update you can only check for a custom ROM. A rooted device is not really required, but a bootloader unlocked device is usually a requirement.

Comment: Thank you for the response @Robert. Do you know where I can possibly find ROMs compatible with my phone model?

Comment: Use your favorite search engine and check [xda dev forums](https://forum.xda-developers.com/). But based on the Android version and the manufacturer you may not find one. You device is a little bit too old, most developers have already switched to a newer device (so you are about five years too late) and Alcatel is not really a popular manufacturer.